# Permanently disable "Enable Dictation" keyboard shortcut in Monterey

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, voice-dictation

Is it possible to permanently disable all keyboard shortcuts that toggle the "Enable Dictation" dialog in Monterey?  In previous versions of macOS, the dialog had a "Don't Ask Again" button, but that's no longer the case:

[image: Enable Dictation dialog]

Furthermore, the option to change the keyboard shortcut to "Off" is gone from Settings:

[image: Shortcut options]

Answer (score 38):

I have **MacOS Monterey 12.2** and can turn off the Dictation shortcut (System Preferences > Keyboard > Dictation > Shortcut):

[image: Dictation Shortcut: Off]

In **MacOS 13 Ventura** it's located in System Settings > Keyboard > Dictation > Shortcut > select "Off".

[image]

For some systems the following is true:

In **Mac OS 13 Ventura**, the "Off" option has been removed. The closest option to that is `Press ️`

[image: Dictation Shortcut: Press ️]

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the model of device instead.  Does your device's keyboard have a built-in "Dictation" key that looks like a microphone icon?  Mine does.

Comment: Oddy, on my M1 MBP running Monterey 12.2.1, `Off` isn't even an option, in it's place is `Press ` which I've selected instead and will still probably be better than the default.

Comment: can confirm that `Press` is better than the default. Not sure what that key actually is, which is sort of the point.

Comment: Thankyou lord!  I can't tell you how many times this thing has popped up by accident  over the years.  Finally getting rid of it.

Comment: I notice this doesn't change the default behavior on the lock screen. When set to `Press` and logged in I can smash the `ctrl` key without dictation turning on. However at the lock screen I hit ctrl a bunch of times to wake the computer, and once i'm logged in sure enough the "Enable Dictation?" dialog has appeared on Sonoma 14.1.1

Answer (score 7):

This was bothering me too, while there's no way to disable the keyboard shortcut entirely. You can fairly easily set it to a combination of keys that you'll never press again. Such as three modifier keys at once followed by slash

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ventura. Whatever the shortcut I set, the popup still comes up when I press the microphone button (F5).

Comment: This is also the  solution for Sonoma (Mac OS 14)

Answer (score 3):

I also find this really annoying on my new MacBook Air. The only way I found out to stop accidental hits (happens for me especially when hitting `F5` to build a LaTeX document in visual studio code / texlab) is to check `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard -> Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys`. This means that accessing volume, play, etc., buttons is a bit more clumsy, requiring holding down `Fn`, but at least accidental hits of the useless dictation key are gone.

Comment: Seems to be bug, but this actually appears to _completely_ disable the search, dictation, and do not disturb keys that I didn't have on my previous mac. They no longer work even with Fn. The other media keys work behind Fn, but these don't.

Comment: This seems to be the only option in Mac OS 13 Ventura. Customizing the keyboard shortcut (as suggested in other answers) does not disable the dictation key (`F5`).

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to just disable this Key[image]

You can do that by installing [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)

Just assign that key to VK_None to disable it entirely, or you can reclaim it to F5, or any other shortcut.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, tx, the only fix for me on MacOS 14 Sonoma :/ Also replaces the now defunct FunctionFlip! 

Answer (score -1):

You can make the icon go away by turning off the Voice Over feature in Accessibility:

1. **System Preferences** > **Accessibility**
2. On the left, scroll down to the "Motor" section, then select **Voice Control**
3. Deselect **Enable Voice Control**

[image: Screenshot of the Accessibility Preferences Pane showing the Voice Control options]

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I already have that turned off. I'm trying to disable all keyboard shortcuts that prompt to turn Voice Control on when it's currently off.